# Delphi функция наподобие wait

Tags: delphi

Есть ли в Delphi функция вроде "wait" (ждать), что бы например когда пишу процедуру, она выполнялась какое-то время....
Вроде такого? :

```
image1.Picture.loadfromfile:='\1.jpg';

wait 5000 // ждать 5 секунд (т. е. через 5 сек происходит такое):

image1.Picture.loadfromfile:='\2.jpg';
```

Comment: Если у вас есть задача, которая должна долго выполняться, то правильно вынести ее в отдельный поток.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `sleep(5000); //ждать 5 секунд`

Comment: Ага, только в случае с картинками могут быть бяки:) Картинки могут не обновляться и тому подобное.

Comment: чего? вторая картинка загрузится сразу после истечения 5 секунд, правда программа замирает на 5 сек, но в крайнем случае можно пользоваться таймером =)

Comment: потому, что пока программа выполняет sleep, некому заниматься отрисовкой экрана. Поэтому, либо самостоятельно, вызывая `Application.ProcessMessage;`, но это не всегда даст хороший результат, либо таймер, либо дополнительный тред.

Comment: Я вотне понимаю, почему вы так беспокоитесь об отрисовке битмапа? Ведь приложение пишется под немаломощную Windows систему, а не под калькулятор =)

Comment: Да будь это хоть точечка на экране. Но если написать что то вида

    Image1.canvas.LoadFromFile('1.bmp');
    sleep(5000);
    Image1.canvas.LoadFromFile('3.bmp');
То первой картинки не увидите, а только вторую через 5 секунд.

Comment: А как иначе? Иначе ни как =) Надеюсь, что вы хорошо знакомы с потоками, так вот они на самом деле не выполняются одновременно. Одновременное выполнение программ невозможно на одном процессоре(только если процессор многоядерный). Потоки выполняются один за другим, имитируя оновременность. Вот так =)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь создать не визуальный наследник класса TTimer и реализовать задержку через него.

```
procedure Button1Click( ... );
var
tmpTimer:TTimer;
begin
    Image1.canvas.LoadFromFile('3.bmp');
    tmpTimer:=TTimer.Create(Application);
    tmrTimer.interval:=5000; //5 sec
    tmrTimer.Ontimer:=Wait;
end;
procedure Wait();
begin
    Image1.canvas.LoadFromFile('3.bmp');
    tmrTimer.enabled:=false;
end;


...
    tmrTimer.free;
...

    //могут быть грамматические ошибки. писал из головы :-)
```

Comment: Мне лично не нравиться вот эта строка

    tmpTimer.free;

как то не принято убивать объект в его же обработчике.

Comment: Стало только хуже, теперь можно накликать-создать 100 таймеров, а освобожден будет только один и непонятно где ..